# Question concerning proving a function is not analytic?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let $f$ be the function $f: C \rightarrow C$ defined by 
$$f(z) = \begin{cases}
e^{-z^{-4}}, &   z\neq0 \\
0, &z=0 \end{cases}$$
Show that $$\lim_{z \rightarrow 0}\frac{f(z)}z$$ does not exist.

So I get that I need to prove f is not analytic at $z=0$ but I'm not really sure how to prove something is not analytic at a specific point. Should I still use CR equations?

Answer (score 0):

No, you just need to show that the specified limit “does not exist”, i.e. that $\frac{f(z)}{z}$ does not converge for $z → 0$. Therefore, it suffices to give a null sequence of complex numbers $(z_n)_{n ∈ ℕ}$ such that
$$\frac{f(z_n)}{z_n}$$
does not converge for $n → ∞$, (but $z_n \overset{n → ∞}\longrightarrow 0$).

*Hint*: For any $n ∈ ℕ$, $|\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}n}| = 1$ and, since $ℂ$ is algebraically closed, there is some $ζ ∈ ℂ$ with $ζ^4 = \mathrm{i}$. Using this, find a null sequence of complex numbers $(z_n)_{n ∈ ℕ}$ such that $\lvert \frac{f(z_n)}{z_n} \rvert$ does not converge.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you very much